# How to calculate "Arctan" and "Pow" of IplImage?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to calculate Gradient Magnitude and Orientation of a garyscale Image using OpenCvSharp. The problem is that "Pow" function seems to not be the right for the IplImage.
I also want to know how can I calculate tan-1 (or arctan) of featureImage.
Thank you

```
        using (IplImage cvImage = new IplImage("grayImage.png", LoadMode.AnyDepth | 
                LoadMode.GrayScale))
        using (IplImage dstXImage = new IplImage(cvImage.Size, cvImage.Depth, cvImage.NChannels))
        using (IplImage dstYImage = new IplImage(cvImage.Size, cvImage.Depth, cvImage.NChannels))
        {
            float[] data = {    0, -1, -1, 2    };
            CvMat kernel = new CvMat(2, 2, MatrixType.F32C1, data);

            Cv.Sobel(cvImage, dstXImage, 1, 0, ApertureSize.Size1);
            Cv.Sobel(cvImage, dstYImage, 0, 1, ApertureSize.Size1);

            Cv.Normalize(dstXImage, dstXImage, 1.0, 0, NormType.L1);
            Cv.Filter2D(cvImage, dstXImage, kernel, new CvPoint(0, 0));

            Cv.Normalize(dstYImage, dstYImage, 1.0, 0, NormType.L1);
            Cv.Filter2D(cvImage, dstYImage, kernel, new CvPoint(0, 0));

            // to calculate gradient magnitude, sqrt[(dy)power 2  +  (dx)power 2]
            dstXImage.Mul(dstXImage, dstXImage);
            dstYImage.Mul(dstYImage, dstYImage);
            IplImage dstXYImage = new IplImage(cvImage.Size, cvImage.Depth, cvImage.NChannels);
            dstXImage.Add(dstYImage, dstXYImage);
            dstXYImage.Pow(dstXYImage, 1/2); //this line not working,output image is black page


            // to calculate gradient orientation, arctan(dy/dx)
            IplImage thetaImage = new IplImage(cvImage.Size, cvImage.Depth, cvImage.NChannels);
            dstYImage.Div(dstXImage, thetaImage); //afterwards need help to calculate arctan 


            using (new CvWindow("SrcImage", cvImage))
            using (new CvWindow("DstXImage", dstXImage))
            using (new CvWindow("DstYImage", dstYImage))
            using (new CvWindow("DstXYImage", dstXYImage))
            using (new CvWindow("thetaImage", thetaImage))

            {
                Cv.WaitKey(0);
            }
```

Comment: In `dstXYImage.Pow(dstXYImage, 1/2);`, `1/2` performs integer division, so this will reduce to `0`.  Essentially, you are taking every pixel to the power of `0`, which will give you a result of all `1`.  You probably have an 8-bit pixel depth, and so intensity `1` will visualize as black.  As such, try replacing `1/2` with `0.5`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reason. Can you help me how to perform the sqrt for the pixel image?

Comment: Sure!  Just replace `1/2` with `0.5`.  That'll find the square root :)

Comment: get an exception, while I set the image Depth to AnyDepth! "depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_64F"

Comment: `dstXYImage` probably doesn't match the same depth as `dstXImage` and `dstYImage`.  Make sure all of the images have the same depth.

Comment: I changed the bitDepth for dstXImage, dstYImage, and  dstXYImage to F32 ------> IplImage dstXYImage = new IplImage(cvImage.Size, BitDepth.F32, cvImage.NChannels);   ----- the output is Black again!

Comment: Did you change the power to `0.5`?

Comment: yes, and I get the same result!

Comment: Ah... it could be because you're normalizing to `[0,1]`.  Try taking your values of the output and multiplying them by `255` or whatever the maximum value of the bit depth is for your image and see your results.  I don't know what else to try other than that!

Comment: it seems that normalizing which is a post-processing here has not much effect on the output, except the change of MatrixType from F64C1 to F32C1 makes the output from full-black to partial-white, no matter what the bitDepth of IplImages are.

Comment: Create a new image that is the same size and make the values all `255`... then multiply this image by `dstXYImage`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "cartToPolar" function for your purpose.
This function calculates the magnitude and angle of 2D vectors.

*magnitude(I)= sqrt(x(I)^2+y(I)^2), 
angle(I)= atan2(y(I), x(I))[ *180 / pi ]*

For example:

```
IplImage dstXYImage;
IplImage thetaImage;
CartToPolar(dstXImage, dstYImage, dstXYImage, thetaImage, true);
```